# Can I use a method from a different class without creating a new object?

Tags: python, class, typeerror

In class `FTM` I have method `check_data_format_input_data`

```
class FTM():
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        self.check_data_format_input_data(input_data)
        self.input_data= input_data
        #SOME CODE

    def check_data_format_input_data(self, input_data):
        #SOME CODE     
        return
```

In class `Topic_embedding`, I want to use the `check_data_format_input_data` method from `FTM`.

```
 class Topic_embedding:
    def __init__(self, input_data):
        FTM.check_data_format_input_data(input_data = self.input_data)
        self.input_data= input_data
```

The code above raises:

```
TypeError: check_data_format_input_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I use FTM's method without creating a new FTM object?

Comment: Make `check_data....` method a `@staticmethod`?

Comment: Make `check_data_format_input_data` a staticmethod

Comment: Question: if you don't need an instance of a class to use a method, then why is the method in the class in the first place? Does it make sense to just define the method as a global function instead? Why do both `__init__()` and `check_data_format_input_data()` take `input_data`? Are these different things? If not then either one or the other should accept the parameter, not both.

Comment: Probably, it should just be a regular function then if you want to use it without an instance. Why put it in a class at all if you want to use it without an instance?

Comment: static method would be good - could also make `FTM` a parent class of `Topic_embedding`